# cherrypy.tree.mount and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, cherrypy

I used to use cherrypy with mod_python and I built my controller trees with `cherrypy.tree.mount` calls and I would like to keep them (they are spread through the code).
Now I have to use mod_wsgi. Example: [from cherrypy wiki](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModWSGI)

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

import atexit
import threading
import cherrypy

cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'embedded'})

if cherrypy.__version__.startswith('3.0') and cherrypy.engine.state == 0:
    cherrypy.engine.start(blocking=False)
    atexit.register(cherrypy.engine.stop)

class Root(object):
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello World!'
    index.exposed = True

application = cherrypy.Application(Root(), script_name=None, config=None)
```

My problem is that every `cherrypy.tree.mount` call creates a `cherrypy.Application`. And mod_wsgi wants **one** object named `'application'`.

I know that you can build a cherrypy tree with class variables but I don't want to do that.

Is there a way to use `cherrypy.tree.mount` and get one application object?

There is also [cherrypy.tree.graft](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/tree.html) but I think it's meant for a different purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally! Got it myself - from the manual...

`cherrypy.tree` is itself a WSGI object so you simply do:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(...)
cherrypy.tree.mount(...)
cherrypy.tree.mount(...)
application = cherrypy.tree
```